# Is there a term for a graph data structure in which a graph node can contain another graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

A hypergraph is a graph in which an edge can connect more than two nodes.

Is there a term for a "nested graph" - a graph whose nodes can "contain" arbitrary graphs?

I have seen this work:

A Nested-Graph Model for the Representation and Manipulation of Complex
Objects
(ALEXANDRA POULOVASSILIS et al)
https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/174608.174610

I wonder if there is a mathematical term for this kind of data structure or any important works I should know of.

Comment: This might be graph smoothing operation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) or some form of edge/vertex contraction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction#Formal_definition)

Comment: I think it may be better to think of working with a graph and a function that maps each graph node to a graph. In this way you are only dealing with simple graphs and functions defined on all graph nodes.